# Fourier transform when function is known

Tags: c++, c, fft, fftw

I have a Fourier transformed function f(w) whose analytical form I know. 
Say

`f(w) = Product of j=1 to 1000 (a1_j * exp (i * w * b1_j) + a2_j * exp (i* w* b2_j)+...+a10_j * exp (i* w* b10_j)+ c_j)`

Where a,b,c are real numbers and "i" is sqrt(-1). 
So even though the the a,b,c's are known function has to computed numerically it is not really analytically tractable.

Now I want to compute inverse transform f(w) to obtain the original function F(x).

My question is partly mathematical and partly software related:

1. I can compute the inverse transform using a available software routines but I am not sure what kind of discrete sampling should I do for f(w) to be able reproduce F(x) faithfully given some tolerance. The domain of F(x) can be quite large. So what is a way out ?
2. Is there any freely available software routines in C/C++ which can take in as input say a functor f(w) and perform the inverse transform for a given "x". If this exist it will bypass my first question (because I guess it will internally handle how many points to use to perform the sampling/integration given any function)

Comment: Um, could is be that you actually want to use Matlab / Octave instead of C++?

Comment: There may be libraries built to handle these sorts of operations, but as @kay said, this is more fitting for a mathematical language.

Comment: Which language, C or C++?  They are different languages.  In C++ there is a `complex` type (`std::complex`) but in C there is only a [macro for complex type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/complex/complex).

Comment: What tolerance do you mean, exactly?  An L infinity?  L 1?  Something else?  By "inverse transform for a given x", you mean evaluate F(x) at a given point?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I would interpret c/c++ here as "I am open to either c or c++ solutions to this problem, whichever is better".

Comment: c or c++ whichever works as Yakk correctly interpreted. @Yakk : yes compute F(x) at a given "x". What I mean by tolerance is the estimate of F(x) should be within certain "tol" of true F(x). We do not know what the true F(x) is but perhaps the estimate gives an "error bar" of some kind.

Comment: That would be the L-infinity norm then.

Answer (score -1):

> Is there any freely available software routines in C/C++ which can take in as input say a functor f(w) and perform the inverse transform for a given "x". If this exist it will bypass my first question (because I guess it will internally handle how many points to use to perform the sampling/integration given any function)

Absolutely classic software for FFT, present on all systems, is

http://www.fftw.org/

On UBuntu, you have to install `libfftw3-dev` and that's it

UPDATE

I could write discretization code, but after looking at function definition

```
f(w) = Product of j=1 to 1000 (a1_j * exp (i * w * b1_j) + a2_j * exp (i* w* 2_j)+...+a10_j * exp (i* w* b10_j)+ c_j)
```

I'm opposing to the statement

> So even though the the a,b,c's are known function has to computed numerically it is not really analytically tractable.

If you look at your function, expand it carefully you'll get linear sum of

f(w) = Sum<sub>k</sub> A<sub>k</sub>*exp(i w B<sub>k</sub>)

Remembering that x-domain and w-domain are pretty symmetric wrt direct and inverse Fourier transformation, if mono-harmonic in x-domain will produce Dirac's δ-function in frequency domain, then mono-harmonic in w-domain will produce Dirac's δ-function in x-domain.

So F(x) would be

F(x) = Sum<sub>k</sub> A<sub>k</sub> * δ(x - B<sub>k</sub>)

Dealing with δ numerically is EXTREMELY cumbersome, so I advise you to drop this whole discretization business and concentrate on how to compute A<sub>k</sub> and B<sub>k</sub> from your f(w) expression.

Comment: Not really an answer unless you can show how to apply this to a parametric function (as opposed to a vector of data).

Comment: Yes correct as Toby Speight pointed out unless I know how to sample correctly a discrete fouurier transform routine is not useful.

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux your treatment shifts the focus away from Fourier transform to something else possibly more cumbersome. i know the a1_j's, b1_j etc. It is numerically easy for me to compute f(w) for a given w. I can create a vector of f(w) easily. The only thing I do not know is what should be the range of w I should choose so that I get and estimate of F(x)

Comment: @user1612986 No, it is not - it is analytical solution for your problem. Sure, you could compute f(w), but in most cases for F(x) you'll get some noise - because sum of deltas is ZERO everywhere except points where you hit exactly B_k. So you made the code, got inverse FFT and then some value - then what? Is this value small enough to treat it as zero? Or maybe you hit one of the peaks? Basically, from shape of f(w) follows very important properties of F(x) - it is ZERO everywhere except several thousand points, where it is equal to infinity. I don't know how to get such properties numerically

Comment: @user1612986 Here is link to some properties of the Fourier transform: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierTransform.html. You could take a look at the table and on fourth line is the correspondence between delta i x-domain and single wave in w-domain.